# Complex delimite columns in Pandas read_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read some log files using Pandas, where the columns are delimited by whitespace, and some columns consist of single quoted strings with whitespace (e.g. `'string   '`). I am having a hard time reading these files with `read_csv`. For example (using some dummy data):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""\
  1   2   'asdf    ' 3
  4   5   'asdfg   ' 4  
""")

columns = ['a','b','c','d']
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True, names=columns)
```

For the first row, this results in columns `1`, `2`, `'asdf`, `'`, `3`, where I would prefer to have it as `1`, `2`, `asdf`, `3`. The behavior makes total sense, but I can't find a way to make `read_csv` parse such files "correctly" (as I want it).

Is this at all possible?

Comment: use `quotechar = "'"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `quotechar` argument while parsing from `read_csv`

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, quotechar = "'", delim_whitespace=True, names=columns)
```

Although this will result in column `c` having extra whitespaces. You can get rid of those using

```
df.c = df.c.str.strip()
```

Comment: Well, didn't expect it to be this easy... :) Thanks!